# Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java

I have a server and client socket program, a server send a encrypted message to client, i.e. 
the server side code:

```
cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 
secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedText, "AES");
cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
feedback = "Your answer is wrong".getBytes();
cipher2.doFinal(feedback);
dos.writeInt(feedback.length);
dos.write(feedback);
```

the client side code:

```
int result_len = 0;
result_len = din.readInt();            
byte[] result_Bytes = new byte[result_len];
din.readFully(result_Bytes);
cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);             
byte[] encrypt = cipher2.doFinal(result_Bytes);
```

Exception throw at `byte[] encrypt = cipher2.doFinal(result_Bytes);`

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2086)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Is result_len a multiple of 16? If not, make sure it is, then result_Bytes should be the right length.

Answer (score 30):

This is a very old question, but my answer may help someone.

- In the encrypt method, don't forget to encode your string to Base64
- In the decrypt method, don't forget to decode your string to Base64

**Below is the working code**

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Base64;

    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

    public class EncryptionDecryptionUtil {

    public static String encrypt(final String secret, final String data) {


        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            // rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
            SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(decodedKey, 16), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error occured while encrypting data", e);
        }

    }

    public static String decrypt(final String secret,
            final String encryptedString) {


        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            // rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
            SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(decodedKey, 16), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedString));
            return new String(cipherText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error occured while decrypting data", e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data = "This is not easy as you think";
        String key = "---------------------------------";
        String encrypted = encrypt(key, data);
        System.out.println(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypt(key, encrypted));
      }
  }
```

**For Generating Key you can use below class**

```
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class SecretKeyGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        int keyBitSize = 256;
        keyGenerator.init(keyBitSize, secureRandom);

        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

 System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: for fixed ```key``` use any 16 char String

Comment: my device sdk is 23. decode works in 26 sdk. Is there an other way?

Answer (score 12):

Had a similar issue. But it is important to understand the root cause and it may vary for different use cases.

**Scenario 1**
You are trying to decrypt a value which was not encoded correctly in the first place.

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedBase64String);
```

If the String is misconfigured for certain reason or has not been encoded correctly, you would see the error " Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher"

**Scenario 2**
Now if by any chance you are using this encoded string in url (trying to pass in the base64Encoded value in url, it will fail.
You should do URLEncoding and then pass in the token, it will work.

**Scenario 3**
When integrating with one of the vendors, we found that we had to do encryption of Base64 using URLEncoder but then we need not decode it because it was done internally by the Vendor

Comment: `Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);`   _works for me_

Answer (score 3):

I know this message is old and was a long time ago - but i also had problem with 
with the exact same error:

the problem I had was relates to the fact the encrypted text was converted to String and to `byte[]` when trying to DECRYPT it.

```
    private Key getAesKey() throws Exception {
    return new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), 16), "AES");
}

private Cipher getMutual() throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    return cipher;// cipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes());
}

public byte[] getEncryptedPass(String pass) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = getMutual();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getAesKey());
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return encrypted;

}

public String getDecryptedPass(byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = getMutual();
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getAesKey());
    String realPass = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
    return realPass;
}
```

Comment: Can you make it clearer in terms of: whether the above code is the one gives problem or is the one solves the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this answer: [Encrypt and decrypt with AES and Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954611/aes-encript-and-decript-problem-with-apache-base64)