# decrypted result 128- aes-CBC difference between mbedtls in C and Java Cipher

Tags: java, c, encryption

I want to encrypt data from a client and send it to a server over a socket. The client is written in Java and the server is written in C. However, the result is not the same as my expected.
The C program as follows:

```
#define MAX_BUFF 1024
#define MAX_LENGTH_DATA 1024
static void decrypt128(unsigned char intput[], unsigned char output[]) {
    mbedtls_aes_context context_out;
    unsigned char key1[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P'};
    unsigned char iv1[16] = { 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P' };
    unsigned char decrypt[128];
    mbedtls_aes_init(&context_out);
    mbedtls_aes_setkey_dec(&context_out, key1, 128);
    mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc(&context_out, MBEDTLS_AES_DECRYPT, 16, iv1, intput,decrypt);


    printf("\nInside of decrypt128 function:\n");

    for (unsigned index = 0; index < 128; ++index)
        printf("%c", (char) decrypt[index]);

    strcpy(output, decrypt);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int socket_desc, client_sock, c, read_size, rc, option = 1, ret,
            encrypt_size, counter_data_receive;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int opt = 1;
    struct timeval timeout_receive;
    unsigned char encrypt_bufferr[MAX_LENGTH_DATA] = { 0 };
    unsigned char decrypt_bufferr[MAX_LENGTH_DATA] = { 0 };

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    printf("Creating socket...!!!!!\n");
    if ((socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 4434
    if (setsockopt(socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt,
            sizeof(opt))) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(4434);

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 4434
    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    printf("Start waiting for incoming connections!\n");
    listen(socket_desc, 1);

    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr*) &client,
            (socklen_t*) &c);
    if (client_sock < 0) {
        printf("Failed: accept connection");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Connection accepted\n");
    timeout_receive.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout_receive.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(client_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,
            (const void*) &timeout_receive, sizeof(struct timeval));

    memset(encrypt_bufferr, 0x00, sizeof(encrypt_bufferr));
    memset(decrypt_bufferr, 0x00, sizeof(decrypt_bufferr));
    ret = recv(client_sock, encrypt_bufferr, sizeof(encrypt_bufferr), 0);

    printf("\n+++++++++++++byte receive: %d\n", ret);
    printf("\n+++++++++++++received buff: %s\n", encrypt_bufferr);

    decrypt128(encrypt_bufferr, decrypt_bufferr);
    printf("\nFinal decrypted data = %s", decrypt_bufferr);

}
```

**output**

```
Creating socket...!!!!!
Start waiting for incoming connections!
Connection accepted

+++++++++++++byte receive: 24

+++++++++++++received buff: 8+4c4xcMC1FPhdJabnl/4w==

Inside of decrypt128 function:
R�V͵2�Q���˵��
```

For the client-side, I wrote it using Java:

```
public class EncryptDecryptString {

    private static final String cipherTransformation    = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    private static final String aesEncryptionAlgorithem = "AES";

    public static String encrypt(String plainText) {
        String encryptedText = "";
        byte iv1[] = { 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P' };

        try {
            Cipher cipher   = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
            byte[] key      = { 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P' };
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithem);
            IvParameterSpec ivparameterspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv1);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivparameterspec);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
            encryptedText = encoder.encodeToString(cipherText);

        } catch (Exception E) {
             System.err.println("Encrypt Exception : "+E.getMessage());
        }
        return encryptedText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) {
        String decryptedText = "";
        byte iv1[] = { 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P' };
        try {
            Cipher cipher   = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
            byte[] key      = { 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P' };//encryptionKey.getBytes(characterEncoding);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithem);
            IvParameterSpec ivparameterspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv1);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivparameterspec);
            Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
            byte[] cipherText = decoder.decode(encryptedText.getBytes("UTF8"));
            decryptedText = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.err.println("decrypt Exception : "+E.getMessage());
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("Enter String : ");
        System.out.println("Running.... ");
        String plainString = "Hello world!";//sc.nextLine();        
        String encyptStr   = encrypt(plainString);
        String decryptStr  = decrypt(encyptStr);

        Socket socketOfClient;
        try {
            socketOfClient = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4434);
            BufferedWriter os = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketOfClient.getOutputStream()));   
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketOfClient.getInputStream()));
            os.write(encyptStr);
            os.flush();

            System.out.printf("\nSent data to server....\n");
            //os.flush();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }             

        System.out.println("Plain   String  : "+plainString);
        System.out.println("Encrypt String  : "+encyptStr);
        System.out.println("Decrypt String  : "+decryptStr);

    }   
}
```

**Output**

```
Running.... 

Sent data to server....
Plain   String  : Hello world!
Encrypt String  : 8+4c4xcMC1FPhdJabnl/4w==
Decrypt String  : Hello world!
```

The received encrypted data is the same between the two sides, but when I used mbedtl to decrypt this data in the server-side, the result is not the same. Please help me to resolve the problem. Thank you!!!!

Comment: In client side you encoded your output to base64 but you didn't decode it from base64 in server side.

Comment: Compare your java decrypt method and your decrypt server side method steps, you can find the problem.

Comment: Hi  behnam arazkhani,Thank you for your reply. The goal is that the server's code will be kept. I've already tried not to encode the data in the client-side, but the decrypted data received on the server-side was not the same as the original data. Could you give me a suggestion?

Comment: Did you receive same bytes in server side?

Comment: I mean same encrypted data. Checks encrypted data before sending to the server and also after receiving in the server side and be sure both are same. note: your padding in the client side is PKCS5 and you don't have it in the server side.

Comment: From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494764/input-length-must-be-multiple-of-16-when-decrypting-with-padded-cipher, I think that we need to add base64 encoder.

Comment: Finally, I found out the root cause of the problem. I still keep the code in the client-side and update code that decodes base64 received data on the server-side. Thank you so much!!!!