# SHA Encryption doesn't work

Tags: java, encryption, sha

Below is the code I have written for SHA encryption. But compiling this, gives an exception

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA SecretKeyFactory not available

Please some one help to solve this? Actually am not familiar with encryption techniques.

Code :

```
public String encrypt(String password)
    {
        try
        {

            KeySpec ks=new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
            SecretKeyFactory skf=SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algo);
            SecretKey key=skf.generateSecret(ks);
            MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(password.getBytes());
            byte[] digest=md.digest();
            byte[] salt=Arrays.copyOf(digest, 16);
            AlgorithmParameterSpec aps=new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20);
            Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance(algo);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, aps);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String password)
    {
        try
        {
            KeySpec ks=new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
            SecretKeyFactory skf=SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algo);
            SecretKey key=skf.generateSecret(ks);
            MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(password.getBytes());
            byte[] digest=md.digest();
            byte[] salt=Arrays.copyOf(digest, 16);
            AlgorithmParameterSpec aps=new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 20);
            Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance(algo);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, aps);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return password;
    }
```

Comment: SHA-2 is no encryption. It's a hash, and thus doesn't offer an efficient inverse operation.

Comment: So is there any other way to encrypt a String using SHA and decrpyt the same

Comment: Can you describe what your code is supposed to do? It makes very little sense. The variable names suggest that you want to hash a password which is totally different from encryption. You should describe your real problem, not the remaining problem after solving the first half of the problem in a wrong way.

Comment: where is the `algo` variable in your code defined?

Comment: @PeterElliott static String algo = "SHA-256";

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to waste your time re-inventing the wheel, you can always go for `org.apache.commons`. Specifically, this is how to do it:

```
String hash = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(password);
```

Add this to your POM and you're good to go:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the failure: `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");`. There is no default implementation of SHA256 hashing available. Also, how are you planning to `decrypt` SHA2? Maybe I fail to understand your intention, but the hash algorithms are meant to be irreversible by design.

**Encryption**

AFAIK the best encryption(not hashing/reversible) algorithm is AES. Here's a good answer on how to use AES.

[Encrypt and decrypt with AES and Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954611/aes-encript-and-decript-problem-with-apache-base64)