# AES Encryption Input Length Error javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, encryption, aes

This is my code:

```
public class Encryption {
    private static final String ALGO = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[]{'F','O','R','T','Y','T','W','O','F','O','R','T','Y','T','W','O'};
    private static Key key = generateKey();

    public static String encrypt(String DATA) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key,new IvParameterSpec(c.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV()));
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(DATA.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String DATA) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(DATA.length());
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(c.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV()));
        byte[] dencVal = c.doFinal(DATA.getBytes());
        String decryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(dencVal);
        return decryptedValue;

    }
    public static Key generateKey() {
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue,"AES");
            return key;
    }
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Error:Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:913)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at Encryption.decrypt(Encryption.java:30)
    at EncryptionTest.main(EncryptionTest.java:9)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code must be indented by 4 spaces (or select it and press Ctrl+K)

Comment: Please describe what the problem is. Where is your main method? What are the inputs? Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt and decrypt with AES and Base64 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954611/encrypt-and-decrypt-with-aes-and-base64-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

`AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` is a "[block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher)" meaning in works on blocks of fixed size, 16 bytes in this case.  Inputs of smaller size must be padded out with extra bytes for encryption to work.

Decryption, because it's working out output of an encryption operation, must already be a multiple of the block size.  The exception is telling you that you have not provided correctly encrypted data because the input was *not* a multiple of the block size.

Decoding should always be the opposite of encoding so if you encode by doing "encrypt then base64-encode" then the decoding must be "base64-decode then decrypt".  Your method is "decrypt then base64-encode" which is pretty clearly a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the returning value of the encrypt method, its not going to work.

You encrypt and then encode the result of the encryption. After that you try do decrypt the encoded value. You have to decode first and then try to decrypt.