# Cannot decrypt when encrypted using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding - input length must be multiple of 16

Tags: java, encryption

I have this encryption code which works no problem. I can decrypt the text it encrypts in another language, but I need to decrypt it in java now.

```
 private static final String AES = "AES";
    private static final String CBC_BLOCK = "CBC";
    private static final String ECB_BLOCK = "ECB";
    private static final String PADDING = "PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String AES_CBC_PCKS5_CIPHER_CONFIG = AES + "/" + CBC_BLOCK + "/" + PADDING;
    private static final String AES_ECB_PCKS5_CIPHER_CONFIG = AES + "/" + ECB_BLOCK + "/" + PADDING;

 public static String encryptInAesEcbPkcs5Padding(String salt, String message) {
        String encryptedMessage = "";
        SecretKeySpec key = null;
        try {
            if (message != null && !message.equals("")) {
                key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), AES);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ECB_PCKS5_CIPHER_CONFIG);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                encryptedMessage = convertMessageToBase64(cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "No such algorithm [" + AES + "]", e);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "No such padding for algorithm [" + AES + "]", e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "Invalid block size for [" + AES + "/" + ECB_BLOCK + "]", e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "Invalid padding [" + PADDING + "]", e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid key [" + key + "]", e);
        }
        return encryptedMessage;
    }
```

Trying to decrypt with this code.  I am using the exact same salt as the encryption and passing in the string the encrypter creates as the "message"

```
public static String decrypt(String message, String salt) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        SecretKeySpec key = null;
        String string = null;
        try {
            if (message != null && !message.equals("")) {
                key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), AES);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ECB_PCKS5_CIPHER_CONFIG);
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                string = new String(decrypted);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "No such algorithm [" + AES + "]", e);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "No such padding for algorithm [" + AES + "]", e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "Invalid block size for [" + AES + "/" + ECB_BLOCK + "]", e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "Invalid padding [" + PADDING + "]", e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid key [" + key + "]", e);
        }
        return string;
    }
```

But i get this error, what am i doing wrong? Seems like it should work. I tried padding the encrypted text with "=" added until it is divisible by 16 but that returns a bad padding error.

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:750)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
```

Comment: This could be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5760584/1416629

Comment: Why don't you perform a base64 decoding before decryption?

Comment: ^ ah this too. Do base64 decoding and get back

Comment: Trying this, makes complete sense, just not getting the decoding quite right yet.  Will update once i fix it.

Comment: tried doing this: byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(message);
                String decoded = new String(bytes);  but this is not working for me, the output is symbols/gibberish

Comment: @pratnala any ideas?

Comment: First, as soon as you encode to base64, decode it back at that point. Print encrypted version, encoded version and the decoded version. All in your encrypted code.

Comment: I dont really have that option right now, the encrypted code was run months ago on some strings, I need to now decode them in java.

Comment: @pratnala got it decoded, now trying to decrypt i get  javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Comment: When i try to remove padding by either change the cipher instance to just AES or AES/ECB/NoPadding, i get it decrypted but its gibberish/symbols

Comment: Since this is really a different problem, I posted a different question.  Go ahead an add your answer if you want and i will mark it correct.  The decoding got me past the error in this post.

Comment: Added as answer. Would help others if they have similar errors :)

Comment: Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Base64 decoding first to reverse the Base64 encoding performed in the original encryption process.