# Java RSA with exchanged keys in socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, io, rsa

I am implementing an RSA Encrypted Socket Connection in Java, for doing that i use two classes the first is the Connection Abstract class which represents the real Socket Connection and the Second is the ConnectionCallback which is a class called when the Connection class receives data.
When data is received by the Connection class, the data gets Decrypted using a before shared public key coming from the connected endpoint (There can only be 1 connected endpoint).

ByteArray class:

```
package connection.data;

public class ByteArray {

    private byte[] bytes;

    public ByteArray(byte[] bytes){
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }

    public ByteArray(){
    }

    public void add(byte[] data) {
        if(this.bytes == null) this.bytes = new byte[0];
        this.bytes = joinArrays(this.bytes, data);
    }

    private byte[] joinArrays(byte[] array1, byte[] array2) {
        byte[] array = new byte[array1.length + array2.length];
        System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array, 0, array1.length);
        System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array, array1.length, array2.length);
        return array;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes(){
        return this.bytes;
    }
}
```

Connection class:

```
package connection;

import connection.data.ByteArray;
import connection.protocols.ProtectedConnectionProtocol;
import crypto.CryptoUtils;
import crypto.algorithm.asymmetric.rsa.RSAAlgorithm;
import protocol.connection.ConnectionProtocol;
import util.function.Callback;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Base64;

public abstract class Connection implements Runnable {

    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    ConnectionProtocol protocol;
    private Callback callback;
    private boolean isConnected = false;

    public Connection() throws Exception {
        this.protocol = new ProtectedConnectionProtocol(new RSAAlgorithm(1024));
        this.callback = new ConnectionCallback(this);
    }

    public Connection(ConnectionProtocol connectionProtocol, Callback callback) throws Exception {
        this.protocol = connectionProtocol;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isConnected){
            try {
                ByteArray data = new ByteArray();
                while(this.in.available() > 0){
                    data.add(this.read());
                }
                if(data.getBytes() != null){
                    callback.run(data);
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void openConnection(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws Exception{
        this.in = new DataInputStream(in);
        this.out = new DataOutputStream(out);
        this.isConnected = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
        this.write(CryptoUtils.encode(((PublicKey) this.protocol.getPublicKey()).getEncoded()));
    }

    private void write(byte[] data) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(new String(data,"UTF-8"));
        this.out.write(data);
        this.out.flush();
    }

    private byte[] read() throws Exception{
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
        int read = this.in.read(bytes);
        if (read <= 0) return new byte[0]; // or return null, or something, read might be -1 when there was no data.
        byte[] readBytes = new byte[read];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, readBytes, 0, read);
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

ConnectionCallback class:

```
package connection;

import connection.data.ByteArray;
import crypto.CryptoUtils;
import util.function.Callback;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class ConnectionCallback implements Callback {

    private Connection connection;

    public ConnectionCallback(Connection connection){
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Object data) throws Exception {
        ByteArray bytes = (ByteArray) data;
        byte[] dataToBytes = CryptoUtils.decode(bytes.getBytes());
        if(this.connection.protocol.getSharedKey() == null){
            X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(dataToBytes);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(spec);
            this.connection.protocol.setSharedKey(publicKey);
        } else {
            //this.so = StrongboxObject.parse(new String(bytes.getBytes()));
        }
    }

}
```

RSAlgorithm class:

```
package crypto.algorithm.asymmetric.rsa;

import crypto.CryptoUtils;
import crypto.algorithm.asymmetric.AssimetricalAlgorithm;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class RSAAlgorithm extends AssimetricalAlgorithm {

    private KeyPairGenerator keyGen;

    public RSAAlgorithm(int keyLength) throws Exception {
        super();
        this.keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        this.keyGen.initialize(keyLength);
        this.generateKeys();
    }

    @Override
    public void generateKeys() {
        KeyPair pair = this.keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        super.setPublicKey(pair.getPublic());
        super.setPrivateKey(pair.getPrivate());
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] message) {
        try {
            super.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (PublicKey) super.getSharedKey());
            return CryptoUtils.encode(super.cipher.doFinal(message));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] message) {
        message = CryptoUtils.decode(message);
        try {
            super.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, (PrivateKey) super.getPrivateKey());
            return super.cipher.doFinal(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }

}
```

ProtectedConnectionProtocol class:

```
package connection.protocols;

import protocol.connection.ConnectionProtocol;
import crypto.algorithm.asymmetric.AssimetricalAlgorithm;

public class ProtectedConnectionProtocol extends ConnectionProtocol {

    private AssimetricalAlgorithm algorithm;

    public ProtectedConnectionProtocol(AssimetricalAlgorithm algorithm){
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPublicKey() {
        return this.algorithm.getPublicKey();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrivateKey() {
        return this.algorithm.getPrivateKey();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSharedKey() {
        return this.algorithm.getSharedKey();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSharedKey(Object sharedKey){
        this.algorithm.setSharedKey(sharedKey);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] message) {
        return this.algorithm.decrypt(message);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] message) {
        return this.algorithm.encrypt(message);
    }

}
```

CryptoUtils class:

```
package crypto;

import java.util.Base64;

public class CryptoUtils {

    public static byte[] encode(byte[] data){
        return Base64.getEncoder().encode(data);
    }

    public static byte[] decode(byte[] data){
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE of 05/09/2019**:
Code update same Exception:

```
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCcrbJGHqpJdhDbVoZCJ0bucb8YnvcVWx9HIUfJOgmAKIuTmw1VUCk85ztqDq0VP2k6IP2bSD5MegR10FtqGtGEQrv+m0eNgbvE3O7czUzvedb5wKbA8eiSPbcX8JElobOhrolOb8JQRQzWAschBNp4MDljlu+0KZQHtZa6pPYJ0wIDAQAB
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 0
        at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:743)
        at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:535)
        at crypto.CryptoUtils.decode(CryptoUtils.java:12)
        at connection.ConnectionCallback.run(ConnectionCallback.java:21)
        at connection.Connection.run(Connection.java:42)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**Please help me i am exasperated with this and have only 2 more days of Bounty, i prefer to give my Bounty to someone who helped me finding the solution to this problem than to lose it.**

Comment: Convert the RSA output base64 after encryption.

Comment: which is the correct way to do that? i just go with: Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));?

Comment: [Should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/encoding-as-base64-in-java) See also [What is base 64 encoding used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201479/1820553)

Comment: Could you update your code?

Comment: @kelalaka the code is already updated i have modified the original Connection class inserting the code necessary to transform bytes into Base64 and viceversa.

Comment: Where is the `message`-parameter of `RSAAlgorithm#encrypt` consumed? This should happen in `doFinal`, right? The same applies to the `encrypted`-parameter in `RSAAlgorithm#decrypt`. Also: Base64-encoding in the `Connection`-class is too late! It must _already_ be done in `RSAAlgorithm#encrypt`. Storing the encrypted data in a string doesn't work in general. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905). Base64-decoding should be performed in `RSAAlgorithm#decrypt`.

Comment: @Topaco so do i encode in base64 immediately after to have encrypted/decypted?

Comment: Encryption: Base64-encode immediately _after_ encryption. Decryption: Base64-decode _before_ decryption. Concerning the order see also e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760584/9014097).

Comment: The posted public key is Base64-encoded. The [`X509EncodedKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html)-ctor in the `ConnectionCallback`-class expects the raw binary data. Obviously the Base64-decoding is missing! In addition, `RSAAlgorithm#decrypt` uses a wrong cast (use `PrivateKey` instead of `PublicKey`), which would create a `java.lang.ClassCastException` later during decryption.

Comment: You don't decrypt with a public key. You *encrypt* with a public key, and you decrypt with the corresponding *private* key.

Comment: @user207421 it's what i am doing

Comment: @Stecco 
In Byte[] encrypt(byte[] message) method, change the return statment and do base64encryption as shown below.

    encodeBase64URLSafe(super.cipher.doFinal(message));

Basically you are trying to base64decode before doing actual decryption.  But you not doing base64encoding after encryption.  Hence its throwing the error.

Comment: @VinothA thanks didn't see it, i will try!

Comment: @Stecco 
Please try the with below statement.  The above statement  will work with apache commons library.  For java util, you have to use the statement as shown below
Base64.getEncoder().encode((super.cipher.doFinal(message)))

Comment: @VinothA wait a moment, in the Connection class in the method write() i am doing the encoding before sending the message should i take that part of the code inside the encrypt method? Also thanks for helping me

Comment: @Stecco Ok didn't see that,  Then please remove the below line from onReadFinished method in Connection class
bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes);
Because I think you are twice decrypting with base64.  Please check

Comment: @VinothA yes i can't belive, that is probably the error because i am decoding on the onReadFinished and on the decrypt method i will check it as soon as i can thanks!

Comment: @VinothA no it's not even that the error i don't know why but when i enter in the ConnectionCallback and print the Key is received in Base64 format when i try to decode it it just stops and throws the IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 0 Exception, at this point if anyone can make the code work i'm fine with it, you can even rewrite it entirely that is not even a problem if it works.

Comment: What is this ByteArray class?

Comment: @GotoFinal it is a class that i have built, it works just like an ArrayList but only for byte[]

Comment: Can you show it anyways? isn't whole issue just caused by your read method? you are always trying to read 8192 bytes, so if you will receive bytes in few parts or just smaller chunks then you will end up with few huge byte arrays ending with a lot of 0.

Comment: And then you would try to use base64 on it, and get `Illegal base64 character 0` error

Comment: I will show the ByteArray class here as fast as i can today, i didn't thought that receiving small chunks of data would end up filling the array with 0s, how can i just solve this problem? My first attempt would be read the array and put the data in to another array till i find some 0s is this enough? Thanks anyways for the reply, this can probably be the solution

Comment: yep, copying array is enough, but might hurt performance a bit, but that depends if you need to care about performance a lot here. see my answer for me info, and I hope it will be it.

Comment: @GotoFinal if your solution solves the problem you will have my bounty i promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by your read method:

```
private byte[] read() throws Exception{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
    this.in.read(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

You are always reading into array of 8192 bytes, even if there isn't enough bytes in input stream. `this.in.read(bytes)` returns amount of bytes read, you should use that value and only use that amount of bytes from this array, ignoring the rest - as rest of array will be just `0`, so when you try to decode base64 from it you will get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 0`

So when reading your bytes you can just copy them to new array:

```
private byte[] read() throws Exception{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
    int read = this.in.read(bytes);
    if (read <= 0) return new byte[0]; // or return null, or something, read might be -1 when there was no data.
    byte[] readBytes = new byte[read]
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, readBytes, 0, read)
    return readBytes;
}
```

Note that reading like that is actually pretty bad idea for performance, as you are allocating a lot of stuff for each read. More advanced libraries like netty have own byte buffers with separate read/write positions and just store everything in single self-resizing array of bytes, but first make it work, and if you will have any issues with performance then remember that this is one of places you might find a solution.

Also in your ByteArray you are coping both arrays into same spot:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < this.bytes.length; i++){
        bytes1[i] = this.bytes[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        bytes1[i] = data[i]; // this loop starts from 0 too
    }
```

you need to use `i + this.bytes.length` in second one. (and it's better to use System.arrayCopy)

```
public byte[] joinArrays(byte[] array1, byte[] array2) {
    byte[] array = new byte[array1.length + array2.length];
    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array, 0, array1.length);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array, array1.length, array2.length);
    return array;
}
```

And then just:

```
public void add(byte[] data) {
    if(this.bytes == null) this.bytes = new byte[0];
    this.bytes = joinArrays(this.bytes, data);
}
```

Also like in that other answer - it might be good idea to change flush method to just set field to null, or even better, just remove that method as I don't see it being used, and you could just create new instance of this object anyways.

Comment: I don't know why this is still not working can you just try this code and see what happens? I have tried anything i have updated the question description with the ByteArray class so please check it out, thanks for the help man i appreciate it!

Comment: added note about error in your ByteArray class @Stecco

Comment: Check if the add method now is correct because it is still throwing me the error

Comment: @Stecco nope, you are still overriding one array with another

Comment: At this point i can't belive that is throwing me another time the same Exception, i reupdate the code and the Exception, as you suggested i have deleted the flush() method.

Comment: If you could please download the code and test it by yourself and give me the solution i would thank you A LOT, but don't  worry, i know that this requires time so if you don't want to do it just don't do it.

Comment: @Stecco oh my, I did a small mistake in my code, make sure to `return readBytes;` in your read method

Answer (score 1):

I looked into your code and figured out that the problem is with the `add()` method in the `ByteArray` class. Let me show you, (*See the comments*)

Original : **ByteArray**

```
public void add(byte[] data){
    if(this.bytes == null)
        this.bytes = new byte[data.length]; 
    byte[] bytes1 = new byte[this.bytes.length + data.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < this.bytes.length; i++){
        bytes1[i] = this.bytes[i]; // when this.bytes is null you are adding data.length amount of 0, which is not something you want i guess. This prevents the base64 decoder to decode
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        bytes1[i] = data[i];
    }
    this.bytes = bytes1;
}
```

Solution: **ByteArray**

```
public void add(byte[] data){
    if(this.bytes == null) {
        this.bytes = data; // just store it because the field is null
    } else {
        byte[] bytes1 = new byte[this.bytes.length + data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.bytes.length; i++) {
            bytes1[i] = this.bytes[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            bytes1[i] = data[i];
        }
        this.bytes = bytes1;
    }
}

public void flush(){
    this.bytes = null; // Important
}
```

> EDIT

After observing the codes that reads bytes in Connection class I found that it's reading unnecessary 0 bytes at the end. So I come up with the following workaround,

Refactor: **Connection**

```
...

public abstract class Connection implements Runnable {

...

@Override
public void run() {
    while(isConnected){
        try {
            ByteArray data = new ByteArray();
            while(this.in.available() > 0){
                byte[] read = this.read();
                if (read != null) {
                    data.add(read);
                }
            }
            if(data.getBytes() != null){
                callback.run(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}

...

private byte[] read() throws Exception{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[this.in.available()];
    int read = this.in.read(bytes);
    if (read <= 0) return null; // or return null, or something, read might be -1 when there was no data.
    return bytes; // just returning the read bytes is fine. you don't need to copy.
}
```

}

Comment: I tried it is still throwing the Exception can you just download the code and test it please?

Comment: @Stecco I have updated my submission. I refactored the read() method in the Connection class which was reading some unnecessary 0 bytes at the end of the data. I hope this time your exception will be gone. Let me know if it works?